# Model framework on top of JPA

Tags: java, jpa, orm, frameworks

so far i've developed my business layers using eclipse EMF technology with teneo on top of hibernate.

While teneo is nice and complete, many of its features are not needed on a sever layer, so
i'm evaluating to start new projects based on JPA specification (hibernate or eclipselink).

What i'm missing  from EMF thought is reverse relationship fixup, or reltaionship collections initializations on entity creation.

is there any light framework do fill this gap?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Texo](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Texo) can generate model, persistence & web service code without EMF dependencies. Further reading: [EMFT Texo: different from EMF code generation?](http://martintaal.wordpress.com/2011/12/06/emft-texo-different-from-emf-code-generation/), [Only Generate Entities - No EMF dependencies](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Texo/Code_Generation_Patterns#Only_Generate_Entities_-_No_EMF_dependencies).